# Is C while pointer going to work with any pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, command-line-arguments, c-strings

I understand that the usual `while (*pointer)` use case is when using string.

```c
char str[]= "string";
int i = 0;
while (*(str + i++));
```

The loop ends when the dereferenced character is `\0`.

But, I have this code that prints out the array of string recursively.

```c
void print_array(char** arr, bool printComma) {
    if (*arr) {
        if (printComma) {
            printf(", ");
        }
        printf("%s", *arr);
        print_array(arr + 1, true);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    print_array(argv, false);
}
```

It worked as expected and prints out the string inside `char **arr`.

However, I don't understand how the system know the end of the array because dereferencing a pointer to pointer will give a value pointing to a memory, which I am not sure what is the value too.

Additionally, if I use this style with any pointer variable, is the loop guaranteed to end?

Comment: There's nothing magic. `*pointer` will be `0` if it was set to point to a location containing `0`. So in the `print_array` example it is the caller of the function that passes in an array of pointers where each pointer is either NULL or not NULL. And since `argv` is being passed in we know it's a series of pointers to strings with a NULL pointer as the last element.

Comment: Perfect example of why we should use explicit coding style. `if (*arr)` is very confusing, `if (*arr != NULL)` is perfectly clear. Similarly, `**arr` would be equally confusing and `**arr != '\0'` would be readable. In particular, `NULL` and `\0` have very different meanings even though they may both boil down to a zero in the end.

Comment: @Lundin My taste differs. I'm not the only one. Quoting K&R: "`/* strcpy: copy t to s; pointer version 3 */
void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
while (*s++ = *t++)
;
}`
Although this may seem cryptic at first sight, the notational convenience is considerable, and the idiom should be mastered"

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica That's an example of horribly written code that everyone (every veteran) knows how it works simply out of experience. Rather than by taking a glance at the code and immediately understanding it. `strcpy` can be written in far more readable ways, but of course the source code turns a couple of lines longer then. In the final machine code, that doesn't matter. K&R was written in an era where source code size on the hard drive was a thing to consider... it's a historical text from the 1970s.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica (Actual library quality strcpy doesn't use that old trick anyhow, but works on alignment basis.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because the `argv` array passed to [the `main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) is terminated by a `NULL` pointer.

That is, `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be `NULL`.

And `NULL` pointers are considered `false` when used as conditions. Like for example `if (*arr)`

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard *5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

> 2 If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey
> the following constraints:
>
> — The value of argc shall be nonnegative.
>
> — **argv[argc] shall be a null pointer**

So in this if statement

```
if (*arr) {
```

there is checked whether the next pointer `*arr` (having the type `char *`) is equal to `NULL` or not.

To make it more clear consider the following demonstrative program where instead of command line arguments there is used a similarly defined array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array( char **arr ) 
{
    *arr == NULL ? ( void )putchar( '\n' )  : ( printf( "%s", *arr ), print_array( arr + 1 ) );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s[] =
    {
        "Hello", " ", "World!", NULL 
    };
    
    print_array( s );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
```